# Status Indicator based on Due Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a "Priority Indicator" column in my SharePoint page which shows a bullet point of either green, yellow or red. I cannot seem to find anywhere any help on how I can code this to link with "Due Date" column.

At the moment my status indicators only show if high, normal or low on "Priority" are selected.

For the "Priority Indicators" the code I have is;

[Priority Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIA09.png)

For my JavaScript code see below;

[JavaScript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4626q.png)

I want the Priority Indicators to show;
Red indicator shows if due date within a week
Yellow indicator shows if due date within 2 weeks
Green indicator shows if due date within 3+ weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup column won't refresh automatically so I suggest you use [CSR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) for this requirement.

Insert script editor webpart into your list view webpart page and insert below script into script editor webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {

            // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render
            var priorityFiledContext = {};
            priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
            priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
                // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View
                "Priority_x0020_Indicators": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
            };

            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);

        })();

        // This function provides the rendering logic for list view
        function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            // get the date set in your date YourDateField
            var itemDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem["Due_x0020_Date"]);
            // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
            itemDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value

            var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds

            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((itemDate.getTime() - today.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
            if (diffDays < 7) {
                return "<span style='color:red'>&bull;</span>";
            } else if (diffDays < 14) {
                return "<span style='color:yellow'>&bull;</span>";
            } else {
                return "<span style='color:green'>&bull;</span>";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Check field static name by developer tool(in list new/edit form).

[image]

Comment: Make sure the field static name matches, Priority_x0020_Indicators Due_x0020_Date

Comment: I did change them but what does x0020 stand for? Should i still have the style code in the formula of the column name? Am i right in putting it in as a Script Editor Web Part?

Comment: SharePoint will encode special character such as blank(_x0020_), check my update.

Comment: This still won't work for me :( here's what I have done; I kept the formula code that changed the colour in the column name but I also took it out and still didn't work. I also took out the content editor and put it in a script editor, is there a step missing/done wrong?